# Repeat matrix n-times into a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a matrix that i want to duplicate n times in a list.
Obviously the rep() function does not work on matrices, so does anyone have a good suggestion how to make this better than my code below?

Thanks!

```
# Create sample matrix
jwprox <- matrix(ncol=15,nrow=15)
# Create list of n-times matrices
jwprox <- list(jwprox,jwprox,jwprox)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `lapply()`

```
n <- 3

x <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(X) jwprox)
str(x)
# List of 3
#  $ : logi [1:15, 1:15] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ : logi [1:15, 1:15] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ : logi [1:15, 1:15] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

or `replicate()`:

```
xx <- replicate(n, jwprox, simplify=FALSE)
identical(x,xx)
# [1] TRUE
```

(FWIW, `replicate()` is just a sometimes-handy wrapper for `sapply()` and, in turn, `lapply()`.)